# CoreAnimation - Measure FPS on device - iOS 8.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, core-animation

How can I meassure the CoreAnimation FPS on device? I mean the number which the CoreAnimation profiler displays. I want to find out when my CoreAnimation FPS go down to decrease the level of detail and make my aniamtions smooth again. The goal is to never allow any lags to happen (for too long).

I know I could use CADisplayLink to meassure the absolute refresh rate but this might be different than the CoreAnimation FPS.

Comment: The Core Animation instrument measures the number of drawn frames per second, which doesn't necessary mean that your app is missing frames. Are you sure that's the number you want to be looking at?

Comment: What I measured was that the CA drawn FPS went down but the FPS I measured with CADisplayLink did not went down (or not that significantly). I'm searching for a way to find out if CA is lagging. Maybe what I was asking for was wrong. Is there a better way than CADisplayLink to find out if CoreAnimation is lagging?

Comment: Another example: I'm currently having a project where I move a CALayer by moving my finger on the screen. CA is heavily skipping frames while doing this, but though the CADisplayLink FPS are 50-60. I want to find out when CA is under heavy pressure and how many frames it skips.